# Replace Pandas Dataframe Values run and Crash Kernel

Tags: python, pandas

I have these values in my Pandas Dataframe, the Dataframe itself have about 400000 rows with one column called "Value".

```
S2_2018_targeted.value.unique()

array(['Yes', 'No', 'N', 'Y', 'YES', 'NO', 'y', ' No ', ' Yes ', '   ',
       nan], dtype=object)
```

I am running this code to change the values but it crashes the Kernel in Jupyter notebook.

```
S2_2018_targeted.replace(to_replace =["No", "N", "No "],  
                            value ="NO")
```

Any other ways I could change my values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a dictionary and focus only on the specific column

```
df.value.replace({'No ': 'NO', 
                  'NO': 'NO',
                  'n': 'NO'})
```

For many values, you can create the dictionary dynamically. Suppose you have

```
to_replace = ["No", "N", "No "]
```

then

```
d = {val: 'NO' for val in to_replace}
df['value'] = df.value.replace(d)
```

Answer (score 1):

If the letters always start with a capital N, may be you can use regex as below

```
df['value'].replace(to_replace=r'\bN(\w+)', value='NO', regex=True, inplace= True)
```

with both capital & small letters. Example, for 'y', 'yes' ,'Y' & 'Yes', this will work 
`df['value'].replace(to_replace=r'\b(Y|y)(\w+)?', value='YES', regex=True, inplace= True)`

Comment: with both capital & small letters. Example, for 'y',  'yes' ,'Y' & 'Yes', this will work `df['value'].replace(to_replace=r'\b(Y|y)(\w+)?', value='1', regex=True, inplace= True)`